# Fetch completion not working in eclipse pydev

Tags: python

I am using Eclipse Neon with Pydev plugin on Windows 10. The python interpreter is Anaconda3.
Some time ago the fetch completion stopped working in debug mode and I am getting the error message below. I upgraded to Photon but still not working. Any help to resolve this will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
Unexpected XML error. Payload:
Error in fetching completionsTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139\pysrc\pydevconsole.py", line 449, in 
   get_interpreter
    interpreterInterface = getattr(__builtin__, 'interpreter')
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'interpreter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception 
 occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.
   py", line 1463, in do_it
    completions_xml = pydevd_console.get_completions(frame, 
     self.act_tok)
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_console.
   py", line 248, in get_completions
    return _pydev_completer.generate_completions_as_xml(frame, 
     act_tok)
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\_pydev_completer.
   py", line 167, in generate_completions_as_xml
    completions = pydevconsole.get_completions(act_tok, act_tok, 
     updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139\pysrc\pydevconsole.py", line 460, in 
   get_completions
    interpreterInterface = get_interpreter()
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139\pysrc\pydevconsole.py", line 451, in 
   get_interpreter
    interpreterInterface = InterpreterInterface(None, None, 
     threading.currentThread())
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139
   \pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console.py", line 25, in 
   __init__
    self.interpreter = get_pydev_frontend(host, client_port)
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139
   \pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 491, 
   in get_pydev_frontend
    _PyDevFrontEndContainer._instance = _PyDevFrontEnd()
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139
   \pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 340, 
   in __init__
    self.ipython = PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell.instance()
  File "C:
   \Users\nathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-
   packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:
   \Users\nathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-
   packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 425, in 
   __init__
    super(TerminalInteractiveShell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:
   \Users\nathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-
   packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 488, in __init__
    self.init_completer()
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139
   \pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 262, 
   in init_completer
    self.Completer = self._new_completer_600()
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139
   \pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 224, 
   in _new_completer_600
    parent=self
  File "C:\Users\nathan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.
   core_6.4.3.201807050139
   \pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 95, in 
   __init__
    IPCompleter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:
   \Users\nathan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-
   packages\IPython\core\completer.py", line 1110, in __init__
    self.dict_key_matches,
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I cracked it, at least for myself.

Updated pydev via the Eclipse Help...Check for Updates - Installed latest available.

AND

pip uninstall ipython (6.2.1)
pip install ipython (6.5)

The latter got it to work, not sure if the former was required.